# Why content projection does not work for root component?

Tags: angular

My root component look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-map-wrapper',
    styleUrls: ['./map-wrapper.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './map-wrapper.component.html',
})
export class MapWrapperComponent {
}
```

And it is registered in root module:

```
bootstrap: [MapWrapperComponent]
```

Template is:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Inside **index.html** I try to use content projection:

```
<body>
    <app-map-wrapper>
        <app-menu></app-menu>
        <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
        <app-map-controls></app-map-controls>
        <app-bottom-right-tools></app-bottom-right-tools>
        <app-map></app-map>
    </app-map-wrapper>
</body>
```

As result I get this in Chrome elements inspector:

```
<app-map-wrapper _nghost-jwi-c262="" ng-version="10.2.4"></app-map-wrapper>
```

Comment: you need to wrap your content inside a component and use routing, usually in the "main" component you can just stamp "...loading" ;)

Comment: I dont have any routing, I have bootstrapped component in roto module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a component used to bootstrap your angular application. Commonly, this component comes out of the box when you create an app with `ng-cli` and it's the `AppComponent`.

So usually the `index.html` looks like this:

```
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

`app-root` is the selector for the `AppComponent`.

Now if you need to bootstrap your application with some other component, you'd have to include that in the `bootstrap` array of the `AppModule`.

`app.module.ts`

```
bootstrap: [MapWrapperComponent]
```

Comment: I have made this already, so I have `bootstrap: [MapWrapperComponent]` in my root module. Why it does not work?

Comment: I just renamed `<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>` on `<app-map-wrapper></app-map-wrapper>`

Comment: I see that content are appears in `<app-map-wrapper>` then immediately disappears

Comment: Could you possibly create a stackblitz snippet which replicates the issue ?

Comment: I can not is it a hard, because I have a lot of dependencies, I can share additional code